Jupyter Notebook error: Unable to allocate / Too large work array required, when calculating inverse matrix
I want to calculate the (generalized) inverse of a 30807 x 30807 matrix.
I tried to use np.linalg.pinv(matrix), and the error "MemoryError: Unable to allocate 7.07 GiB for an array with shape (30807, 30807) and data type float64" occurred.
I tried to use sp.linalg.pinv(matrix), and the error "ValueError: Too large work array required -- computation cannot be performed with standard 32-bit LAPACK." occured.
Which one (numpy or scipy) is preferred for the calculation of inverse matrix? Or anyways, can I solve one of the above errors?
I use jupyter notebook on Windows 11 system. RAM is 16 GB, so I think 7.07 GB should be able to allocate.
I have read Jupyter Notebook error: Unable to allocate 8.12 GiB for an array with shape (22370, 389604) and data type uint8 (tried changing memory but still fail) and Unable to allocate array with shape and data type and so on, but I am still not clear which memory I should set and which value for memory I should choose (if this is the solution to my problem).
And I do not know how to see whether I currently use 32bit or 64bit version of python in jupyter notebook.

Both numpy.pinv() and scipy.pinv() use singular value decomposition to compute the Moore-Penrose inverse, which requires additional memory for matrices u, s, vt. In your case the program consumes at least 21GB of memory approximately.
Convert the matrix to float32 with mat = mat.astype(np.float32) should work.
Other things you can try are

Break down the inverse computation process and store some of the temporaries on disk
Use another SVD implementation such as scipy.sparse.linalg.svds and sklearn.decomposition.TruncatedSVD
Use another approach that avoids SVD to compute pseudoinverse


Thanks for the answer. When I tried to convert the matrix to float32 and calculate its inverse, the warning "RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in cast  s = s.astype(_realType(result_t), copy=False)" exists, and a null matrix returns. What would be the reason behind that? Because the accuracy is not sufficient after converting to float32? Or is the program disrupted because of run time?

I also tried to use spyder as alternative IDE. In spyder, the error init_gesdd failed init occurred when calculating inverse after converting to float32.
